# Cakephp configuration of all the htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp-2.0

I have a cake php app at "http://sakibshamim.com/DhakaGate/" directory. But it is showing 404 error with "The requested URL /app/webroot/ was not found on this server".

I have configured 3 .htaccess file at "DhakaGate" folder, "DhakaGate/app" folder and "DhakaGate/app/webroot" folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the book on loading mod_rewrite -

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

or

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

depending on what version you're using

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your .htaccess files like this

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried this one. Without **RewriteBase** 500 Internal Server Error is showing.

Comment: Yes. Is there anything I have to do?